# How to keep only the events with less than 3 minutes time difference in R

Tags: r

I have big dataset where each row has timestamp, so 400k rows and each has time of the event. 
What I would like to do is to keep only the ones which have time difference less than 3 minutes (of course I would like to vary this parameter later).

Every row is one message, where one of the columns contains exact time when it is sent. I want to see how many messages would be left if I would set the 3 minute interval between messages. So I need a code which will delete message if it is sent less than 3 minutes after previous one.

```
     TIME_STAMP             PREV_TIME_STAMP      Unique ID 
06-27-2021 07:07:22       06-27-2021 06:30:00         1 
06-27-2021 04:38:55       06-27-2021 04:21:31         1 
06-27-2021 05:05:26       06-27-2021 02:55:00         1 
06-27-2021 14:32:39       06-27-2021 12:30:00         1 
06-27-2021 14:42:13       06-27-2021 14:32:39         1 
06-27-2021 15:18:05       06-27-2021 15:11:00         2 
06-27-2021 15:19:05       06-27-2021 15:18:05         2 
06-27-2021 12:31:37       06-27-2021 12:30:00         2 
06-27-2021 12:35:05       06-27-2021 12:30:00         2
```

I am coding in R.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide example data, e.g. using `dput(df)`.

Comment: Please use the edit function to include the example in your question above. And restrict your data example to `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: So, I need him that for same unique ID, keeps only the events which had happened within 3 minutes difference.   Meaning 3 minutes after previous message. So refference for calculation is previous message and it can be changed, as some of them will be deleted (the ones with time difference less than 3 minutes) and some of them can be kept.

Comment: Output is the same, but it just have to be filtered based on the condition explained

Comment: The previous message time is the one indicated in the `PREV_TIME_STAMP` column or the `PREV_TIME` of the preceding row? Both answer assume the former

Answer (score 1):

First you have to change the columns as datetime object (`POSIXct`).
Then a simple difference will find which row to keep and which to discard:

```r
df$TIME_STAMP <- as.POSIXct(df$TIME_STAMP, format = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
df$PREV_TIME_STAMP <- as.POSIXct(df$PREV_TIME_STAMP, format = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')
```

Or using the `anytime` package

```r
df$TIME_STAMP <- anytime::anytime(df$TIME_STAMP)
df$PREV_TIME_STAMP <- anytime::anytime(df$PREV_TIME_STAMP)
```

Luckily the time difference is reported in minutes

```r
df[df$TIME_STAMP - df$PREV_TIME_STAMP > 3,]
#>            TIME_STAMP     PREV_TIME_STAMP Unique_ID
#> 1 2021-06-27 07:07:22 2021-06-27 06:30:00         1
#> 2 2021-06-27 04:38:55 2021-06-27 04:21:31         1
#> 3 2021-06-27 05:05:26 2021-06-27 02:55:00         1
#> 4 2021-06-27 14:32:39 2021-06-27 12:30:00         1
#> 5 2021-06-27 14:42:13 2021-06-27 14:32:39         1
#> 6 2021-06-27 15:18:05 2021-06-27 15:11:00         2
#> 9 2021-06-27 12:35:05 2021-06-27 12:30:00         2
```

With `dplyr`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(-Unique_ID), ~as.POSIXct(., format = '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S')) %>% 
  filter(TIME_STAMP - PREV_TIME_STAMP > 3)
#>            TIME_STAMP     PREV_TIME_STAMP Unique_ID
#> 1 2021-06-27 07:07:22 2021-06-27 06:30:00         1
#> 2 2021-06-27 04:38:55 2021-06-27 04:21:31         1
#> 3 2021-06-27 05:05:26 2021-06-27 02:55:00         1
#> 4 2021-06-27 14:32:39 2021-06-27 12:30:00         1
#> 5 2021-06-27 14:42:13 2021-06-27 14:32:39         1
#> 6 2021-06-27 15:18:05 2021-06-27 15:11:00         2
#> 7 2021-06-27 12:35:05 2021-06-27 12:30:00         2
```

Data:

```r
df <- read.table(text = 'TIME_STAMP          PREV_TIME_STAMP      Unique_ID 
"06-27-2021 07:07:22" "06-27-2021 06:30:00"         1 
"06-27-2021 04:38:55" "06-27-2021 04:21:31"         1 
"06-27-2021 05:05:26" "06-27-2021 02:55:00"         1 
"06-27-2021 14:32:39" "06-27-2021 12:30:00"        1 
"06-27-2021 14:42:13" "06-27-2021 14:32:39"         1 
"06-27-2021 15:18:05" "06-27-2021 15:11:00"         2 
"06-27-2021 15:19:05" "06-27-2021 15:18:05"         2 
"06-27-2021 12:31:37" "06-27-2021 12:30:00"         2 
"06-27-2021 12:35:05" "06-27-2021 12:30:00"         2', header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I interpret you correctly, you can convert the time stamp to POSIXct class, then add 3mins to PREV_TIME_STAMP and filter for those TIME_STAMP is more than 3 mins after PREV_TIME_STAMP

```
DT[TIME_STAMP >= PREV_TIME_STAMP + 3*60]
```

or using `difftime`

```
DT[difftime(TIME_STAMP, PREV_TIME_STAMP, units="mins") > 3]
```

output:

```
#             TIME_STAMP     PREV_TIME_STAMP UniqueID
# 1: 2021-06-27 07:07:22 2021-06-27 06:30:00        1
# 2: 2021-06-27 04:38:55 2021-06-27 04:21:31        1
# 3: 2021-06-27 05:05:26 2021-06-27 02:55:00        1
# 4: 2021-06-27 14:32:39 2021-06-27 12:30:00        1
# 5: 2021-06-27 14:42:13 2021-06-27 14:32:39        1
# 6: 2021-06-27 15:18:05 2021-06-27 15:11:00        2
# 7: 2021-06-27 12:35:05 2021-06-27 12:30:00        2
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
DT <- fread("TIME_STAMP,PREV_TIME_STAMP,UniqueID 
06-27-2021 07:07:22,06-27-2021 06:30:00,1 
06-27-2021 04:38:55,06-27-2021 04:21:31,1 
06-27-2021 05:05:26,06-27-2021 02:55:00,1 
06-27-2021 14:32:39,06-27-2021 12:30:00,1 
06-27-2021 14:42:13,06-27-2021 14:32:39,1 
06-27-2021 15:18:05,06-27-2021 15:11:00,2 
06-27-2021 15:19:05,06-27-2021 15:18:05,2 
06-27-2021 12:31:37,06-27-2021 12:30:00,2 
06-27-2021 12:35:05,06-27-2021 12:30:00,2")[, ':=' (
        TIME_STAMP = as.POSIXct(TIME_STAMP, format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S"),
        PREV_TIME_STAMP = as.POSIXct(PREV_TIME_STAMP, format="%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S")  
    )]
```

Comment: It is not accurate. the problem is that i need code that for same unique ID, keeps only the events which had happened within 3 minutes difference. Meaning 3 minutes after previous message. So refference for calculation is previous message! and it can be changed, as some of them will be deleted (the ones with time difference less than 3 minutes) and some of them can be kept

Comment: Maybe u can add the desired output in your OP? As you can see, both of us are interpreting your qn identically.